# unable to use "=" sign in cross-env-shell

Tags: npm

here is a simple npm script to describe the problem

```
"test":"cross-env-shell \"echo testing=123\""
```

will not print any thing

but if I do this

```
"test":"cross-env-shell \"echo testing\""
```

testing is print out

```
"test":"cross-env-shell \"echo 123\""
```

123 is print out

so seem like equal sign cause the issue, how can I solve this?

Comment: For future reference, this is tracked in https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/246 and my understanding is that it's a wontfix because the package is not maintained anymore